# How to visualize a 5-D mix data using bubble charts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize 5-D mix data using bubble charts by leveraging the concepts of hue, size and depth.
I used the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
t = fig.suptitle('Wine Residual Sugar - Alcohol Content - Acidity - Total Sulfur Dioxide - Type', fontsize=14)

xs = list(iris_data['SepalLengthCm'])
ys = list(iris_data['SepalWidthCm'])
zs = list(iris_data['PetalLengthCm'])
data_points = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(xs, ys, zs)]

ss = list(iris_data['PetalWidthCm'])
colors = ['red' if wt == 'red' else 'yellow' for wt in list(iris_data['Species'])]

for data, color, size in zip(data_points, colors, ss):
    x, y, z = data
    ax.scatter(x, y, z, alpha=0.4, c=color, edgecolors='none', s=size)

ax.set_xlabel('Sepal Length')
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal Width')
ax.set_zlabel('Petal Length')
```

But it is giving the following error:

`operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (0,4) and requested shape (1,4)`

`<Figure size 576x432 with 1 Axes>`

I am adding the full trace of the error I am getting:

```
Text(0.5, 0, 'Petal Length')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2191                            else suppress())
   2192                     with ctx:
-> 2193                         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2194 
   2195                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1861 
   1862             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 1863             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   1864                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1865 

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in draw(self, renderer)
    443                             for axis in self._get_axis_list()) + 1
    444         for i, col in enumerate(
--> 445                 sorted(self.collections,
    446                        key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),
    447                        reverse=True)):

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py in <lambda>(col)
    444         for i, col in enumerate(
    445                 sorted(self.collections,
--> 446                        key=lambda col: col.do_3d_projection(renderer),
    447                        reverse=True)):
    448             col.zorder = zorder_offset + i

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py in do_3d_projection(self, renderer)
    492         fcs = (_zalpha(self._facecolor3d, vzs) if self._depthshade else
    493                self._facecolor3d)
--> 494         ecs = (_zalpha(self._edgecolor3d, vzs) if self._depthshade else
    495                self._edgecolor3d)
    496         sizes = self._sizes3d

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py in _zalpha(colors, zs)
    808     norm = Normalize(min(zs), max(zs))
    809     sats = 1 - norm(zs) * 0.7
--> 810     rgba = np.broadcast_to(mcolors.to_rgba_array(colors), (len(zs), 4))
    811     return np.column_stack([rgba[:, :3], rgba[:, 3] * sats])

<__array_function__ internals> in broadcast_to(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in broadcast_to(array, shape, subok)
    178            [1, 2, 3]])
    179     """
--> 180     return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
    181 
    182 

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py in _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok, readonly)
    121                          'negative')
    122     extras = []
--> 123     it = np.nditer(
    124         (array,), flags=['multi_index', 'refs_ok', 'zerosize_ok'] + extras,
    125         op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (0,4) and requested shape (1,4)

<Figure size 576x432 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: You don't mention where exactly you get the error. Posting a full trace would be helpful.  Are you sure you are using the latest matplotlib (3.4.1) and pandas (1.2.3) versions?

Comment: I have added the full trace. Please check.
Yes, I have the latest matplotlib and pandas version.

Comment: Can you confirm that the standard 3D plotting works on your system? E.g. [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/lines3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-lines3d-py) and [other examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#d-plotting).  Could you simplify your question's code, e.g. by replacing the dataframe by just 5 short lists of numbers? (e.g. `xs=[1,2,3,1,5]` etc.)

Comment: @JohanC Yes, it's working!